# How do I stop display and another email of changes when running aptitude full-upgrade after receiving apticron email notifying of the same changes?

Tags: ubuntu, aptitude, cron, ubuntu-11.04

My home server used to run Ubuntu 10.10 server with `apticron` installed, which periodically (via `cron`) sends emails when updates to your installed packages are available. This email includes a list of the changes in the packages thanks to `apticron`'s dependency on `apt-listchanges`.

I recently rebuilt the server from scratch after a hard disk failure, this time using Ubuntu 11.04 server but with this newer Ubuntu, when I receive one of the `apticron` "Updates available" emails and log into the server to run `aptitude full-upgrade` to install said updates, `aptitude` displays the same list of changes and requires me to quit the pager before it will install the updates. It also sends me another email with the same list of updates in it again. This change in default behaviour from 10.10 to 11.04 is starting to irritate me. **How do I turn off the "display changes when upgrading" feature**?

I've tried uninstalling `apt-listchanges` which does prevent the changes being shown when doing the `aptitude full-upgrade`, but unfortunately stops the list of changes from being shown in the `apticron` emails, which I want to keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, I should have read the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/apt-listchanges.1.html). On Ubuntu 11.04, `/etc/apt/listchanges.conf` looks like this:

```
[apt]
frontend=pager
email_address=root
confirm=0
save_seen=/var/lib/apt/listchanges.db
which=news
```

So I changed `frontend` to `text` and removed `email_address` to give this

```
[apt]
frontend=text
confirm=0
save_seen=/var/lib/apt/listchanges.db
which=news
```

which means the changes are not emailed to me when running `aptitude full-upgrade` and although they are still output to the terminal, they just whiz by without requiring me to quit the pager.

Curiously, on another server where I still have Ubuntu 10.10, I see that this configuration file is exactly the same as the first version above. But apparently this doesn't work properly in Ubuntu 10.10 as I've never seen the changes again or received the additional email when performing upgrades on this server.